# Azure AD B2C unable to localize 'The password must have at least 3 of the following:'

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have been extracting Azure AD B2C strings for a custom translation, and have been having difficulty finding the right identifiers for the string 'The password must have at least 3 of the following:'.

I am using a User Flow Policy Type.
Sign up and sign in flow type.
Password complexity: Strong.

In the Azure Portal, I have downloaded the template for the 'Change password page' of my custom language.
I have modified the file to test, then uploaded the file.

Mostly this is working (after finding missing entries and creating them).

From what I can tell, the missing element should be:

```
{
  "ElementType": "PredicateValidation",
  "ElementId": "StrongPassword",
  "StringId": "CharacterClasses",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "hy:The password must have at least 3 of the following:"
}
```

but, when uploading this, a validation error is returned and the upload fails.

`1 Validation errors found in upload overrides for api.selfasserted.localaccountpasswordchange2.1. Please ensure that your uploaded resource matches the template: The localized string with ElementType: PredicateValidation, ElementId: StrongPassword and StringId: CharacterClasses is not a valid override.`

[Change password page showing untranslated string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdUhF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:

Try:

```
{
    "ElementType": "InputValidation",
    "ElementId": "CustomPassword",
    "StringId": "CharacterClasses",
    "Override": true,
    "Value": "The password must have at least 3 of the following:"
}
```

This uploads.

Comment: Thanks, that did indeed upload.
In my situation, by changing the ElementId to "StrongPassword" it started using the altered string.